# Set the style of GtkLinkButtons

Tags: c++, gtk

I want to use the abilities of a GtkLinkButton, but its design disturbs me. Rather than having a blue underlined text, I'd like it to look like a normal GtkButton.

What I tried is to use this code on my button:

```
GtkWidget *button = gtk_link_button_new_with_label  ("region panel", "Input Sources");
gtk_button_set_relief (button, GTK_RELIEF_NORMAL);
gtk_button_set_use_underline (button, FALSE);
```

However, instead of changing the design, it simply does nothing.

Comment: Does a "C" tag wouldn't suit this question better that a "C++" tag?

Comment: Does it really "disturb" you? You can't sleep at night? Might be worth re-examining your priorities. :)

Comment: @YSC: Not if the OP is writing C++, no...

Comment: It is needed to fix a bug in gnome-control-center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to look like a GtkButton, then just replace it with that. You are not using any abilities that are special to GtkLinkButton.

You just need to make sure your click handler callback is getting fired. You are connected to "activate-link", however this signal will not exist on a standard GtkButton

Have a look here for the available signals.
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html